# How to change directions of a sprite added to View AndEngine?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using AndEngine.

I have a Method that adds targets to the screne.

Here is my method..

```
public void addTarget(){
    /*
     * We are determining the minimum and maximum y position for the targets to appear at then
     * use the Random() class to generate a random number so the value of y is
     * still on the screen while the x value replaces the sprite just before the right side or the screen.
     * 
     */
    Random rand = new Random();

    int x = (int) mCamera.getWidth() + mTargetTextureRegion.getWidth();
    int minY = mTargetTextureRegion.getHeight();
    int maxY = (int)(mCamera.getHeight() - mTargetTextureRegion.getHeight());
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int y = rand.nextInt(rangeY) + minY;

    Sprite target = new Sprite(x,y,mTargetTextureRegion.clone());
    SceneMainScene.attachChild(target);

    int minDuration = 2;
    int maxDuration = 4;

    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = rand.nextInt(rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(actualDuration, target.getX(), - target.getWidth());

    target.registerEntityModifier(mod);
    TargetsToBeAdded.add(target);
```

It works fine. The only problem i am having is that the Targets come onto the screen from left to right.. I would like to change this so the Targets are displayed from top to bottom?

I cant figure out in my code what i need to change to do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a

```
MoveXModifier mod = new MoveXModifier(actualDuration, target.getX(), - target.getWidth());
```

try using a

```
MoveYModifier mod = new MoveYModifier(actualDuration, target.getY(), - target.getHeight());
```

In AndEngine (0,0) is the top left corner, X increase going to the right and Y increase going down

Comment: When i replaced the code nothing happens. The sprites dont appear on the screen. When i switch it back to the original it works. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The sprite probably doesn't shows because it is created outside the screen and move outside the screen. Try putting in to e from a value that you are sure is inside the windows, just to check if the movement is right. If so, then change the 2 points, keeping in mind andengine's coordinate system

Comment: Could you post that in the answer?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 what do you mean with "Could you post that in the answer?"?